# Unable to upload video from C# (4.7 version) code to Azure media service

Tags: c#, sql, reactjs, azure, extjs

I am trying to upload video from c# to azure media service but unable to do it.Please help me if anyone have any idea how i can do it.

```
static CloudMediaContext m_MediaContext;
static readonly string _AADTenantDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMSAADTenantDomain"];
static readonly string _RESTAPIEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMSRESTAPIEndpoint"];
static readonly string _AMSClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMSClientId"];
static readonly string _AMSClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMSClientSecret"];


azureadtokencredentials tokencredentials = new azureadtokencredentials(_aadtenantdomain, new azureadclientsymmetrickey(_amsclientid, _amsclientsecret), azureenvironments.azurecloudenvironment);
var tokenprovider = new azureadtokenprovider(tokencredentials);
m_mediacontext = new cloudmediacontext(new uri(_restapiendpoint), tokenprovider);                               uploadmedia(assetcreationoptions.none, imagename, file);



static private IAsset CreateAsset(string i_sAssetName, AssetCreationOptions i_AssetCreationOption)
{
var objAsset = m_MediaContext.Assets.Create(i_sAssetName, i_AssetCreationOption);
return objAsset;
}


static public void UploadMedia(AssetCreationOptions i_Option, string i_sFilePath, System.Web.HttpPostedFile file)
        {
            //Form a Name for asset
            var sDynamicAssetName = "Asset_" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();

            //Create a empty asset
            var objAsset = CreateAsset(sDynamicAssetName, i_Option);

            //Get filename with extension which needs to be associated with asset
            var fileName = i_sFilePath; //Path.GetFileName(i_sFilePath);

            //Create the asset file
            var objAssetFile = objAsset.AssetFiles.Create(fileName);

            //Create an AccessPolicy instance that defines the permissions and duration of access to the asset.
            var accessPolicy = m_MediaContext.AccessPolicies.Create(sDynamicAssetName, TimeSpan.FromDays(365 * 100), AccessPermissions.Write | AccessPermissions.List);

            //Create a Locator instance that provides access to the asset.
            var locator = m_MediaContext.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.Sas, objAsset, accessPolicy);

            //Updoad the asset to Azure Storage
            var uploadStream = file.InputStream;
            //objAssetFile.Upload(i_sFilePath);
            objAssetFile.Upload(uploadStream);
            var hlsURI = objAsset.GetHlsUri();
            var mpegDashUri = objAsset.GetMpegDashUri();
            //Finally, Some Cleanup
            locator.Delete();
            accessPolicy.Delete();
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to be *much* clearer. Currently we've got two sentences of description and then random bits of code dump with no explanation. We don't know what happens with your current code, or what you've tried to fix it.

Comment: You have not told what error you encountered. Have you stepped through the code in a debug session?

Comment: I got this error
while i am trying to upload video
"Azure Media Services endpoint Uri schema is not valid"

Comment: you are naming the asset by attaching timestamp,  it will **not** be acceptable to use "/" separator in your asset names. try to remove special chars and test. problematic line is  `var sDynamicAssetName = "Asset_" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();`

Comment: The asset name cannot have these special characters !*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[] , as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/assetfile?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Also, max length is 260 chars.